# Send email via Powershell and Outlook

Tags: email, powershell, outlook

I have a .msg file on my filesystem. With powershell I can open a Outlook window with the message simply like this:

```
Invoke-Item "MY MAIL.msg"
```

How to change the subject and forward it to a given address via Powershell?

Thanks in advance

Comment: You have not accepted @Iain answer (which seems the correct one). I'm experiencing the same annoying popup (Office 2003). Did you work around in some way Iain's answer or adopt any alternative solution?

Comment: any final solution with full source code sample about it?

Answer (score 4):

We had a problem that required the email to be forwarded from Outlook, there was 3000~ emails to do.

The answer Iain had given led me down the path to success, so thank you.

However it did not work for me as given, it failed. I noticed that you need to save the method of the forward to a variable and then execute the code from that, below is my complete script for looping through each msg file in a folder and forwarding it to a person.

I also left the subject as it was and gave no body as this was not needed.

```
#Open Outlook and get a list of emails to forward
$Outlook = New-Object -comObject Outlook.Application 
$Emails = Get-ChildItem -Path C:\Users\APerson\Documents -Filter *.msg

#Loop through each email and open it up
Foreach($Email IN $Emails){
    $Message = $Outlook.Session.OpenSharedItem($($Email.FullName))
    $Forward = $Message.Forward()
    $Forward.Recipients.Add('a.person@gmail.com') 
    $Forward.Send()

    #Sleep is optional :D
    Start-Sleep -Seconds 1
}

#Close Outlook
$Outlook.Quit()
```

Also noticed if you have a security policy applied to Outlook that is stopping you from running this script, for example it will remove the Add() on recipients, just import these registry settings (can be saved as a reg file):

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Policies\Microsoft\office\14.0\outlook\security]
"PromptOOMSend"=dword:00000002
"PromptOOMAddressBookAccess"=dword:00000002
"PromptOOMAddressInformationAccess"=dword:00000002
"PromptOOMMeetingTaskRequestResponse"=dword:00000002
"PromptOOMSaveAs"=dword:00000002
"PromptOOMFormulaAccess"=dword:00000002
"PromptSimpleMAPISend"=dword:00000002
"PromptSimpleMAPINameResolve"=dword:00000002
"PromptSimpleMAPIOpenMessage"=dword:00000002
```

Comment: This worked great! I'm using Outlook 2013, and I just had to change the registry path to: HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Policies\Microsoft\office\15.0\outlook\security

Answer (score 3):

You could try something like this, works with outlook 2010

```
$ol = New-Object -comObject Outlook.Application 
gm -InputObject $ol
$mail = $ol.Session.OpenSharedItem("C:\Users\fred\Desktop\Test Email Subject.msg")
$mail.Forward()
$Mail.Recipients.Add("fred@bloggs.com") 
$Mail.Subject = "Test Mail" 
$Mail.Body = " Test Mail 22222 "
$Mail.Send()
```

Comment: hi, it works but i get some annoying security pop-ups and messages from outlook that make using this script useless for my purpose as i need to mass-forward some thousands of email

Comment: I dont get that warning in outlook 2010, but i know the warning you are talking about, in previous outlook interop work i did, i tried implementing a security shim, but never got it working
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa140152%28office.10%29.aspx
Hope this helps

Comment: @Iain, hi, do you now whether this annoying pop-up is present in Office 2007? Are you sure is not present in 2010? Wouldnt it mean decrease security features?

Comment: You could try signing the script another option is to try the shim i mentioned above

Comment: Signing the script will do nothing. Your options are listed at http://www.outlookcode.com/article.aspx?id=52

Answer (score 0):

In PowerShell 2.0 there is a Send-MailMessage cmdlet that allows you to attach files, specify a subject and a recipient e.g.:

```
Send-MailMessage -smtpServer smtp.doe.com -from 'joe@doe.com' `
                 -to 'jane@doe.com' -subject 'Testing' -attachment foo.txt
```

Not sure how that plays with .msg files but you might give it a try.